# Não posso imprimir objetos usando template string?

Tags: javascript

Por que template string não imprime objetos corretamente? Tenho o seguinte código de teste:

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,}
console.log(`Novo Obj ${obj}`)
```

e o resultado no console sai como:

```
Novo Obj [object Object]
```

não entendo, por que se eu peço pra imprimir sem a template, `console.log('Novo Obj ', obj)` ele imprime certo

```
Novo Obj  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Não posso imprimir objetos usando a template?

Comment: Você provavelmente está se referindo ao Visual Studio Code (ou apenas VS Code) e não Visual Code Studio. Se sim, ele não é só pra JavaScript, tem suporte pra diversas linguagens, incluindo o Java. A segunda pergunta é completamente diferente da primeira, a faça em uma outra pergunta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando você faz `console.log('Novo Obj ', obj)`, está passando o objeto como um dos argumentos de `console.log` (a vírgula separa os argumentos, então a string `'Novo Obj'` é o primeiro argumento, e o objeto é o segundo).

Ou seja, `obj` é tratado "isoladamente" e impresso conforme a implementação - ou seja, varia conforme o ambiente: testando no Chrome e no Node, e o resultado foi `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`, no Firefox foi `Object { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`, e no *snippet* do site, o resultado é:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

Rode e veja a diferença (aperte <kbd>F12</kbd> e compare a saída do *snippet* abaixo com o console do seu *browser*):

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
console.log(obj);
```

Repare que no caso acima, há aspas em volta de a, b e c, e há quebras de linha entre eles (no caso do Chrome e Firefox, obtive o resultado sem as aspas e tudo em uma única linha). O fato é que o resultado de `console.log` varia conforme a implementação, mas em linhas gerais, "todas" imprimem os atributos e valores do objeto.

---

Já quando você coloca o objeto dentro de uma *template string*, internamente é chamado o seu método `toString`. Mas como você não definiu este método no seu objeto, ele usa o [método herdado de `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), que sempre retorna algo como "[object type]" - sendo que `type` será o tipo do mesmo, que no seu caso é `Object`.

Sendo assim, uma forma de resolver é definir o método `toString` no seu objeto:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,
    toString: function() {
        return `a=${this.a}, b=${this.b}, c=${this.c}`;
    }
};
console.log(`Novo Obj ${obj}`); // Novo Obj a=1, b=2, c=3
```

Claro que se quiser, pode usar [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (que costuma ser uma maneira rápida, fácil e por isso muito usada para este propósito):

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,
    toString: function() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
};
console.log(`Novo Obj ${obj}`); // Novo Obj {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
// ou use JSON.stringify diretamente
console.log(`Novo Obj ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`); // Novo Obj {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

---

Um porém com `JSON.stringify` é quando você tem referências circulares:

```js
let a = { x: 1 };
let b = { y: 2, z: a }; // "b" tem referência para "a"
a['z'] = b; // "a" tem referência para "b"

console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // erro
```

Aí você teria que usar [algo assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993) para resolver. Mas aí eu acho mais fácil sobrescrever `toString` e colocar os campos que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Usando o template literal funciona um pouco diferente, nesse caso precisa serializar o objeto usando por exemplo [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), ou acessar as propriedades:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

console.log(`Novo obj.a ${obj.a}`);

console.log(`Novo obj completo ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`)
```